# how do you call javascript from native android code

Tags: javascript, android, webview, webclient

i know that, from this website, in order to call javascript function of a webpage from android is 
      webview.loadUrl("javascript:CALLME()")

my question is, i need to first load the page first where i have my javasctip function CALLME() defined right?

in other words

i should have

```
  webview.loadUrl("http://myweb.com/web.html)  // web.html has javascript CALLME() defined
  webview.loadUrl("javascript:CALLME()");
```

right??

apparently, CALLME() is not getting called

please help

Answer (score 0):

Have you check it?

```
 webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg()");
```

provided you have

```
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```